# pythonでWAVEファイルをfloat型で読み込む方法

Tags: python

pythonにおいて
waveファイルをfloat型に変換し計算したいのですが
なにか良い方法はありますでしょうか
ご教授くださいませんか？

Answer (score 1):

WAVEファイルを1フレームずつ読み込み、Floatのリストとして返す例を作成しました。

```
import wave
import struct
from pprint import pprint

PATH = "/path/to/some/audio.wav"


def main():
    with wave.open(PATH) as f:
        length = f.getnframes()
        floats = [struct.unpack('f', f.readframes(1)) for _ in range(length)]
    pprint(floats)
    return floats


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## 参考

[7.1. struct — バイト列をパックされたバイナリデータとして解釈する — Python 3.6.5 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/struct.html)
[22.4. wave — WAVファイルの読み書き — Python 3.6.5 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/wave.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます　参考にさせていただきます